# How to properly self test a testing framework?

Tags: testing

I saw the code of a few testing frameworks and most of the times it contained self-tests. I mean they used the framework to test itself, not a different testing framework to test theirs. I always found it odd, because at start you have nothing to test with and even if you have something, then you cannot be sure that it does not give false positives because of a bug. I am curious, is there a strategy we could follow to develop testing frameworks in a reliable way with self-tests only?

Comment: The general approach is called *bootstrapping*. Search for that term.

Comment: I don't understand. Do you think it's strange that test framework developers test the framework itself? Why would they *not* do that?

Comment: @I0b0 I meant that they test the framework they develop with the framework itself. And when they start to develop it they have nothing to test with...

Comment: @BobDalgleish I am not sure I understand how bootstrapping is related to this. Can you elaborate?

Comment: I think people are unfairly downvoting this question. If I understand you right, you are basically asking how the testing frameworks can know they work if they use themselves to test it. That would indeed leave open spaces where an mistake would not be caught and could propagate false positives into higher abstractions.
To resolve this, you create a well-defined basic subset of operations, basically the core of your testing framework in this case, that is highly covered by code that isn't necessarily part of your framework. Then you can build more complex features using that well tested core.

Comment: @Joe Any idea how big that core should be for a testing framework? Actually I might be able to check that by existing frameworks.

Comment: @inf3rno Big enough that you can build on top of it, small enough that you can test it easily still. There's no good answer here, because it all depends on requirements. 
To elaborate a bit more on bootstrapping: The first C compiler was written in assembly. Once you had that working C compilation program, you could then write a new compiler in C that is compiled using that compilation program. Now you'd be fully in the C domain.

Comment: If you want to get your mind blown, consider that Kent Beck and Erich Gamma wrote JUnit using TDD on a plane during a flight. So, not only did they test JUnit using JUnit, they actually wrote the tests *first*.

Comment: @JörgWMittag I guess it means that the core is really small for a testing framework. I'll check JUnit, I always liked java code, because most of the libs are elegant and well designed.

Comment: @Joe I don't mind being downvoted, it is just how this site works. Most people vote without thinking. It is a herd behavior. By other questions/answers I got massive plus points and sometimes I have the feeling that I don't even know what I am talking about...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

["Bootstrapping"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bootstrapping_(compilers)) is a compiler term.  It means "write enough of the compiler to support a subset of your source programming language, so that you can write the remainder of the compiler using that language subset."

Tests are written for the subset to prove that it works properly.  Once that's done, you can use the subset to write a "self-hosting compiler."   You would use the same principles to write a test framework with "self-hosting tests."